# Passing <a> tags in an object and programmatically clicking them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am working on building out a navigation component which maps over an array of objects giving each navigation button a link to route to. I am using styled components to make clickable div components which serve as my nav buttons. The links are being passed in as formatted JSON, something like: `{ link: <a href="#123">Sub 1</a> }`.  When I click the navigation tab I want to programmatically click this link.

I have tried using window.location.replace and only passing the href in the object.  This works however it is not the desired solution for our project.

I also tried styling the nav component itself as an `<a>` element however it is quite tricky to style an `<a>` tag element.

So I have my styled component:

```
const SubNavTabOpen = styled.div`
  width: 16.25rem;
  padding: 1.125rem 2.1875rem 1rem 3.3125rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 1.375rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #1a2d3b;
  color: ${basic[500]};
  font-family: ${primaryFont};
  font-size: ${typeScale.paragraph1};
  &:hover {
    color: ${basic[100]};
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  &:focus {
    background-color: #434e59;
    color: ${basic[100]};
    outline: none;
  }
```

```
<SubNavTabOpen
   tabIndex="0"
   data-testid={"sub-nav-open-" + index}
   onKeyDown={(e) => handleRedirect(e, navItem.link)}
>
   <div>{navItem.link}</div>
</SubNavTabOpen>
```

I am thinking that I will add a `name` property to the data object so that I don't actually render the `<a>` element to the page.  The main reason for this is the `<a>` element doesn't fill all of the space required so users could click some areas of the navigation component and not get rerouted.

My handle events should do some type of programmatic clicking

```
  const handleRedirect = (e, link) => {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      link.click();
    }
  };
```

The `link.click()` in the above code doesn't actually run and this is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: why are you not just calling handleMainRedirect? No reason to call click. It is also weird enter is not already triggering click.

Comment: `onKeyDown={(e) => e.key === "Enter" && handleMainRedirect(navItem.link)}`

Comment: Handle main redirect is just another function.  It still needs the code to programatically redirect the user.